# Problems with the Rightside page using reledpar/reledmac

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I have a problem with the right side page of the `\pages` environment using `\reledpar`. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}    
    
    
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside} \beginnumbering \firstlinenum{2} \linenumincrement{2}
            \pstart
            \section{LOREMMMMM} r mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vestibulum placerat justo. Vivamus finibus elementum urna consectetur interdum. Mauris serdum urna.
            \pend
            
            \pstart
            \section{IPSUMMM} Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vestibulum placerat justo. Vivamus finibus elementum urna consectetur interdum. Mauris serdum urna.          
            \pend       
            
            
        \endnumbering \end{Leftside}
        
        \begin{Rightside} \beginnumbering \numberlinefalse
            \pstart
            \section{LOREM IPSUM} Fusce a porttitorauris sed augue tincidunt lacus iaculis dapibus non vel leo. Donec a magna et libero pharetra varius a quis\footnoteA{Noooooote} ipsum. Nam eget tincidunt sapien. Aliquam enim metus, egestas id tellus in, accumsan interdum urna.
            
            \subsection{IPSUM}
            Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vestibulm urna.
            
            \subsection{LOREM}
            Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vestibulum rna.
            \subsection{Commento}   Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras urna.
            \pend
            
            \pstart
            \section{LOREM IPSUM} Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vestibulum placerat justo. Vivamus finibus elementum urna consectetur interdum. Mauris sed augue na.
            
            \subsection{IPSUM}
            Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vestibulum placerat justo. Vivamus finibus elementum urna consectetur interdum. Mauris sed augue\footnoteA{jjddododo} tindum urna.
            
            \subsection{LOREM}
            Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vestibulum placerat justo. Vivamus finibus elementum urna consectetur interdum. Mauris sed augue tinciduntet tincidunt sapien. Aliquam enim metus, egestas id tellus in, accumsan interdum urna\footnoteA{djdjdjdjdjd}.
            \subsection{Commento}   Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante, malesuada congue tortor vel, vesti
            \pend
            
            \endnumbering \end{Rightside}
        
    \end{pages}
    
    \Pages
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code, or other ones even more complex, the left side is correct, while on the right side there are two problems: (1). The first line of each `\section` or `\subsection` has a bigger white space; (2). The familiar notes of this side are grouped up and put on a left page at the end of the document. I don't know why. I tried everything but I couldn't fix the problem. The thing is that it is only on the right pages!

Comment: Hey @Enrico, did you have a chance to try out my solution?

Answer (score 0):

### 0. How to make a MWE

I have taken the liberty of cleaning up your sample code.

TeX.SX requires users to post a ***Minimal** working example* (MWE). This means: Your sample code should contain *only* what is strictly necessary (minimal) to *effectively* produce a document (working) that still *exhibits* your issue (example).

The rationale is: removing all the unnecessary "noise" from your code helps the community help you.

Having removed all the superfluous packages from your code, I still can see the two problems you addressed.

[image: Original problems: awful spacing and misplaced footnotes]

### 1. Solving the awful spacing

Reading the manual, as always, pays off. Specifically, let's look at [p. 71](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf#page=71):

You should put a standard sectioning command (`\chapter`, `\section` etc.)

- either outside of a `\pstart ... \pend` environment
- or as the *optional argument* of a `\pstart`, in which case it will be executed right before said `\pstart` (so, effectively, both solutions are the same).

```
\pstart[\section{Title}]
Text...
```

Also please take the following advice to improve (your code and) your document:

- Leaving a line empty, in (La)TeX, generally makes a new paragraph.
  But with `reledmac`, the right way to make a new, fully functioning paragraph, is *explicitly*: write `\pend` and then `\pstart`. You should *avoid leaving empty lines* inside a `\pstart` environment, because it can make for odd spacing or lineation.
- When you need to add a new (sub)section, proceed as described above: `\pend \pstart[\subsection{Title}]`.
- `reledpar` works only if you have *the same number* of explicit paragraphs on both sides. In the following example, I have balanced the paragraphs from your sample text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}  % only for the sake of presentation
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering 
\firstlinenum{2} \linenumincrement{2} 
\pstart[\section{LOREMMMMM}]
Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante
\pend
%
\pstart
(more text)
\pend
\pstart
(more text)
\pend
\pstart
(more text)
\pend
\endnumbering 
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering 
\numberlinefalse
\pstart
[\section{LOREM IPSUM}]
Fusce a porttitorauris sed augue tincidunt lacus iaculis quis.\footnoteA{Noooooote}
\pend
\pstart
[\subsection{IPSUM}]
Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum.
\pend
\pstart
[\subsection{LOREM}]
Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum.
\pend
\pstart
[\subsection{Commento}]
Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras urna.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

[image: Improve the awful spacing]

Now the spacing is up to LaTeX's reputation for elegant typesetting! Onwards to fixing the footnotes.

### 2. Solving the misplaced footnotes

Here we have an unfortunate case where the info in the manual (p. 20) appears to be wrong:

> Line numbering can be disabled with `\numberlinefalse`. **This feature must be used with caution.** ...
> It could be used in the following cases:
> You want only familiar footnotes, not critical footnotes ...

This is *not* (no longer?) the case. In fact, if you use `\numberlinefalse` in a numbered portion that contains *even **familiar** footnotes*, you run into the above issue, of footnotes shifting to a later page in the document.

So you should *keep the numbering enabled*, but make it "undetectable" to the eye. Luckily, we can take the advice [on the next page](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/reledmac.pdf#page=21):

> You do not want to have the line number in the margins, but do want to use
> critical footnotes. In this case, set `\firstlinenum` to a big value, such as 100,000.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}  % only for the sake of presentation
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering 
\firstlinenum{2} \linenumincrement{2} 
\pstart[\section{LOREMMMMM}]
Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum. Nulla enim ante
\pend
%
\pstart
(more text)
\pend
\pstart
(more text)
\pend
\pstart
(more text)
\pend
\endnumbering 
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside} 
\beginnumbering 
\firstlinenum{100}
\pstart
[\section{LOREM IPSUM}]
Fusce a porttitorauris sed augue tincidunt lacus iaculis quis.\footnoteA{Noooooote}
\pend
\pstart
[\subsection{IPSUM}]
Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum.
\pend
\pstart
[\subsection{LOREM}]
Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras malesuada quam vel eros ornare condimentum.
\pend
\pstart
[\subsection{Commento}]
Fusce a porttitor mi. Cras urna.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

And here is the desired outcome:

[image: Good spacing and good footnotes]